# PHP MySQL User Online In Last 10 Minutes

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I can not get a list of users who have been online in the past 10 minutes.

```
$online = mysqli_query($db_server,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) <= user_last_login") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($users_online = mysqli_fetch_array($online))
{
$users_on = $users_online['user_name'];
echo $users_on;     
}
```

user_last_login is type datetime

Comment: It displays no users and if I change <= to >=, it displays all users.

Comment: Stupid question I know, but you have users which have logged in in the last 10 minutes?

Comment: Yes. Date is like 2011-06-24 02:11:06.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    $ten_minutes_ago = time() - (60 * 10);

    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ten_minutes_ago);

    $online = mysqli_query($db_server,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_last_login >= '$datetime'") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_server));

    while ($users_online = mysqli_fetch_array($online)) {
        $users_on = $users_online['user_name'];
        echo $users_on;
    }
```

Comment: +1 but you wrote `msqli` please update your code: EDIT: sorry the question is tag mysql but example shows mysqli

Comment: Could be a timezone issue? (the timezone of the datetime you are saving as the user_last_login might be different than the timezone of the datetime you are using in the query)

Comment: I think you are right. Query is using a datetime that is 2 hours ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly use MySQL date function, and you can use following query.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,user_last_login,NOW()) < 10;
```

For more references, SEE 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html
.